# Page not directed (Hyperlink)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone tell me why my link cannot be redirected to this particular page? This is my code, I used jQuery menu:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lavalamp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
var dleft = $('.lavalamp li.active').offset().left - $('.lavalamp').offset().left; 
var dwidth = $('.lavalamp li.active').width() + "px";

//apply the current position of active item to our floatr element
$('.floatr').css({
    "left": dleft+"px",
    "width": dwidth
});

$('.lavalamp li').hover(function(){

    var left = $(this).offset().left - ($(this).parents('.lavalamp').offset().left + 15);
    var width = $(this).width() + "px";
    var sictranslate = "translate("+left+"px, 0px)";

    $(this).parent('ul').next('div.floatr').css({
        "width": width,
        "-webkit-transform": sictranslate,
        "-moz-transform": sictranslate
    });

},

function(){

    var left = $(this).siblings('li.active').offset().left - ($(this).parents('.lavalamp').offset().left + 15);
    var width = $(this).siblings('li.active').width() + "px";

    var sictranslate = "translate("+left+"px, 0px)";

    $(this).parent('ul').next('div.floatr').css({
        "width": width,
        "-webkit-transform": sictranslate,
        "-moz-transform": sictranslate

    });

}).click(function(){

    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

    return false;

});

});
</script>
```

---

```
 <p><div class="lavalamp magenta">
<ul >
    <li class="active">
    <a href="http://localhost:52731/MCR/HomeUser.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Inventory</a></li>
    <li><a href="">My Reservation</a></li>
    <li><a href="">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Log Out</a></li>

</ul>
    <div class="floatr"></div>
</div></p>
```

---

When I clicked Home, the page didn't do anything. Tell me what should I do.
P/s : Replaced with hyperlink, but still the same.

Comment: Is your link correct? Is the server running on port `52731`?

Comment: Yeah, my port is on 52731 and the link is absolutely correct. That's is why Im bit confused here.

Comment: Is there an error log you can provide?

Comment: Can you load the page if you paste that link directly into your browser?

Comment: No error it just not direct me to the page.

Comment: why you using **localhost:52731** ?? can't you use the something like **~/MCR/HomeUser.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the JQuery menu plugin is doing something with the raw HTML that make up the menu. Try inspecting the element to confirm this.

- What is the JQuery plugin you are using?
- Can you provide the HTML after the page has loaded?

I can then help further..

SR

**EDIT:**

I believe you should not put the HREF URL on the menu item itself, but instead use a simple href="#" and make sure you give the menu items an id value.

You would then bind to the click event of either the class or id of the  element using:

```js
$(".classname,#idofelement").click( function() {
    // do your stuff
});
```

For a tutorial on lavalamp, please refer to this page:

http://www.queness.com/post/530/simple-lava-lamp-menu-tutorial-with-jquery

Also, you can redirect using this in the click handler:

```js
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

You can find the class or id of the element that was clicked in the click handler by using something similar to:

```js
if($(this).attr("id") == "myelement") {
    // redirect here using window.location
} else {
    // etc
}
```

Hope this helps!